# How to echo a variable and string in one line when calling powershell in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I call powershell in batch and double quote the powershell commands like this:

```
Powershell -commands "&{...}"
```

In the powershell commands I have a $counter=0 and it changes (eg 3) in a for loop. Now I wanna echo "3 objects found" on screen.

I've tried some methods mentioned online, but none of them worked for me. Probably because I've already used " " to quote the powershell commands, I can only use ' ' inside.

I've tried

```
echo(write-output) $counter objects found
echo '$counter objects found'
echo '$($counter) objects found'
$counter='0' echo '$counter objects found'
```

I expect to see

```
3 objects found
```

but I get

```
3
objects
found   #or
$counter objects found  #or 
$($counter) objects found
```

An alternative way would be to pass the value of $counter back to batch, but I think it's easier to do the echo in powershell. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is, this `powershell -NoP -C "$Counter=0;1..3|%{$Counter++};'{0} objects found' -f $Counter"` retuns here `3 objects found`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to powershell and can't understand your code. But write-host solved my problem well. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
$counter = 0

echo(write-host -NoNewline) "$counter objects found"
```

and I got

> 0 objects found

Add arguments after `write-host`. Hope I could help you out!

Edit:

`powershell -NoP -C "$Counter=0;1..3|%{$Counter++};'{0} objects found' -f $Counter"`

Worked for me in batch, posted by @LotPings

Comment: okay, but @LotPings already provided this command: `powershell -NoP -C "$Counter=0;1..3|%{$Counter++};'{0} objects found' -f $Counter"`

Comment: Oh thanks. write-host -nonewline without the quote does work. 
BTW echo " .. " doesn't work because I'm actually running
powershell -commands "&{echo"...";}" in batch

Comment: actually, just write-host without -nonewline or quote will work